# Ubuntu 18.04 Intel Wifi 9560 not working

Tags: intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I cannot get my wifi card to get working. Ive tried different kernel versions and downloaded the latest firmware from intel webside and copy them into lib/firmware. When running dmesg | grep iwl i get the following:

```
[    6.506586] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode failed with error -2 
[    6.506594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-37.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.506599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-36.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.506603] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-35.ucode failed with error -2
[    6.534493] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.554368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    6.607409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 34:e1:2d:d0:6e:48
[    6.686327] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.713180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

A solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep wlp` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and there is a bug 
`kernel BUG at /build/linux-vxxS7y/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:425!`

```
    bp@bp-ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
    [    3.797275] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    3.822539] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 34.0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
    [    3.836082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
    [    3.842661] kernel BUG at /build/linux-vxxS7y/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:425!
    [    3.842665] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(+) coretemp(+) mac80211 kvm_intel(-) snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm snd_hda_core mxm_wmi snd_hwdep irqbypass snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event pcbc eeepc_wmi snd_rawmidi asus_wmi sparse_keymap wmi_bmof snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer aesni_intel snd btusb btrtl btbcm aes_x86_64 iwlwifi btintel crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd nvidia_uvm(OE) input_leds intel_cstate bluetooth soundcore intel_rapl_perf cfg80211 ecdh_generic shpchp mei_me mei wmi mac_hid acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid uas hid usb_storage nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea e1000e sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ptp drm pps_core i2c_i801
    [    3.842694] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rxq_alloc_rbs+0x1d0/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842707]  _iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x252/0x710 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842710]  iwl_pcie_rx_init+0x2d/0x3c0 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842715]  ? iwl_mvm_nic_config+0xeb/0x120 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842718]  iwl_trans_pcie_start_fw+0x2a1/0x6c0 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842723]  iwl_mvm_load_ucode_wait_alive+0xec/0x2b0 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842728]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x8e/0x330 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842731]  ? iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x8e/0x330 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842734]  ? iwl_wait_init_complete+0x20/0x20 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842738]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x649/0x920 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842742]  ? iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x649/0x920 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842745]  _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.10+0x4c/0xa0 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842747]  iwl_opmode_register+0x75/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
    [    3.842751]  iwl_mvm_init+0x38/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
    [    3.842793] RIP: iwl_pcie_rxq_alloc_rbs+0x1d0/0x1f0 [iwlwifi] RSP: ffffae30442978a8
```